# How to customize the command prompt?

Tags: command-line

I'm willing to change my command prompt to be something like

```
user$
```

where `user` is not `root` and

```
root#
```

When the current user is `root`. I've searched for that and found that this is achieved through the `\$` special character and now I have something like this in my ~/.bashrc

```
PS1="\u\$ "
```

Unfortunately, the `\$` is not displayed as a `#` when the current user is `root`. For example, after executing

```
user$ sudo bash
```

I get my command prompt

```
root$
```

Instead of

```
root#
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you set it in your `.bashrc`, not root's.

Comment: @muru added the same assignment to `/root/.bashrc`, but nothing appears to be changed!

Comment: Presumably because some variable still points to you as the use. Try `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in your `~/.bashrc`

```bsh
if [ "$(whoami)" = "root" ]; then PS1="\u# "; else PS1="\u\$ "; fi
```

when you open a new terminal you will get,

```
user$
user$ sudo bash
root#
```

**Note:** It will work only with `sudo bash`. As `sudo -i` or `sudo su` will check `/root/.bashrc` instead of user's `.bashrc`. To get the same behavior copy the same in `/root/.bashrc` also.

#### Alternate Better Way:

The same thing can be achieved by setting `PS1` as

```
PS1="\u\\$ "
```

in user's as well as root's `.bashrc`

Comment: It is. Thank you so much! Is the question confusing? Do you suggest any edits?

Comment: @Kareem no I just overlooked that line, sorry.